# Idea need for Android webview

Tags: android, webview

I am learning Android, I am hanged on one point. I am unable to load webview on a specific webview ID on xml file. below is my java code:

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        WebView webView = new WebView(this);
        webView.setClickable(true);
        webView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://dikoso.in/android/mlm/registration.php");
        WebClientClass webViewClient = new WebClientClass();
        webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
        WebChromeClient webChromeClient=new WebChromeClient();
        webView.setWebChromeClient(webChromeClient);
        setContentView(R.layout.load_registration);
        setContentView(webView);
    }
```

Below is XML file:

```
<WebView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webViewreg"
        android:layout_below="@+id/loginlogo"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

I want to load webview at ID "webViewreg" only, I dont know how to do it. please help guys

Comment: why do you have these 2 `setContentView(R.layout.load_registration);
        setContentView(webView);`?

Comment: follow http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `setContentView(R.layout.load_registration);` the WebView with android:id="@+id/webViewreg" already is loaded. You may find it with findViewById. So try this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.load_registration);

    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewreg);

    webView.setClickable(true);
    webView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("http://dikoso.in/android/mlm/registration.php");
    WebClientClass webViewClient = new WebClientClass();
    webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
    WebChromeClient webChromeClient=new WebChromeClient();
    webView.setWebChromeClient(webChromeClient);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried as you said. but below error showing:
   Error:(16, 39) error: incompatible types
   required: WebView
   found:    View

Comment: I forgot about the cast to WebView class, sorry. I have edited the answer.